# How to keep state in sql CASE WHEN expressions

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I want to fetch the critical status of of errors from an SQL table which holds error information of some devices.

The critical status of an entry could be A , B or C. A is slightly critical, B is moderately critical and C is highly critical.

There could be multiple entries per a device. For example, as in following table.

```
DId     | Critical Status    
Device1 | A
Device2 | B
Device1 | C
Device3 | C
Device1 | B
Device4 | A
```

Now I want to get the maximum critical status against each device. From above example table, I want the following result

```
DId     | Critical Status    
Device1 | C
Device2 | B
Device3 | C
Device4 | A
```

Device Id's need NOT be in order. Any order is okay. I just want to get the most critical value against each device.

How can I write an sql query for that using mysql?

**Edit - I saw some answers which suggest using the MAX function assuming that the critical status is in alphabetical order. I do get those answers. But is there a way to achieve the result if the strings are different. I.e - Open, InProgress and Resolved instead of C, B, A.**

Comment: I think `SELECT MAX(Status)` will work in your case

Comment: Are the codes really A,B,C or this is just a simplification you've done?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Yes that was a simplification I did. My bad, shouldn't have done that. Is there a way to achieve this if A,B,C were replaced by some random strings?

Comment: Wrote you some answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      DId
           ,elt(max(field (CriticalStatus,'Open','InProgress','Resolved')),'Open','InProgress','Resolved')            

from        MyTable

group by    DId
```

or

```
select      DId
           ,substring(max(concat(case CriticalStatus when 'Open' then '1' when 'InProgress' then '2' when 'Resolved' then '3' end ,CriticalStatus)),2)     

from        MyTable

group by    DId
```

or

```
select      DId
           ,case max(case CriticalStatus when 'Open' then 1 when 'InProgress' then 2 when 'Resolved' then 3 end) 
                when 1 then 'Open' 
                when 2 then 'InProgress' 
                when 3 then 'Resolved' 
            end   

from        MyTable

group by    DId
```

Comment: Third one is the best since it uses standard SQL.

Comment: Clean answer. Just what I expected. What I like best is the simplicity of the answer

Answer (score 2):

In order to your status priority, it seems respects alphabetical order, so you can write this:

```
SELECT DId, MAX(CriticalStatus)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY DId
```

See [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c57f3c/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

Try below query

```
SELECT ID, 
       CASE 
         WHEN status = 1 THEN 'Resolved' 
         WHEN status = 2 THEN 'InProgress' 
         WHEN status = 3 THEN 'Open' 
       END critical_status 
FROM(
  SELECT ID, 
       MAX(CASE 
            WHEN Critical_Status = 'Resolved' 
             THEN 1 
            WHEN Critical_Status = 'InProgress' 
             THEN 2 
            WHEN Critical_Status = 'Open' 
             THEN 3 
           END) status
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY ID) T1
```

Hope this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the chars are "in order", just use their numeric value:

```
SELECT ID, 
       MAX(critical_status) status
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
ORDER by status desc;
```

Sérgio

Comment: Why not simply use `MAX(critical_status)`? It will give A, B, C matching the desired result.

Comment: (1) This is not the requested result (2) if the encoding contains ordered alphabetic characters then all you need is max(critical_status)

Comment: Hi Dudu, you are right.. it was returning the char value.. thx [edited]

Comment: ORDER BY <ordinal position> is deprecated and not good programming practice. Do `ORDER BY status desc` instead! (However, it looks like OP wants `ORDER BY Did`...)